# In gmail app, calendar and contacts, can be opened separately. How we can open another app from main app

Tags: android-studio, navigation

I was using gmail, I found that gmail app can access google calendar and contacts under google apps tag in navigation drawer. My point is, how we can access another app. I have made two separate apps and I want to give such link in my third app.

Answer (score 0):

Friends,
Recently, on some google search I found that

```
private String packge_name = "com.android.calculator2";
    private String class_name = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
    private Button bt;
```

Then put the code

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            launchCall();
        }
    });

}

protected void launchCall() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packge_name, class_name));
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```